# Using API level 15, my pendingIntent is not sending the extras for top intent in the taskStack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I am developing an app with a minimum SDK of 15 and target SDK of 29. The app has a series of activities (a list, a detail, a list, a detail, etc.) that the user can navigate through as they deep-dive into their database of information. In the fourth activity, the user has the option of setting an alarm as a reminder.

Currently, the alarm is set and fires off on the given day. However, when you click on the notification, the taskStack is not formed correctly because the extras are not included for the top level of the intent.

To create the notification, I have the following code in CourseDetailActivity:

````
        if(canSetAlarm(when)) {
            String notificationIdString = notificationIdPrefix + courseId;
            int notificationId = Integer.parseInt(notificationIdString);
            long notificationWhen = getNotificationTime(when);
            PendingIntent pendingIntentForContent = createPendingIntentForThisCourse(courseId);

            Intent intent = new Intent(CourseDetailActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_KEY, getString(R.string.course_tracker_notification_channel_id));
            intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);
            intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_TITLE_KEY, title);
            intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_TEXT_KEY, message);
            intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_PENDING_INTENT_KEY, pendingIntentForContent);

            PendingIntent pendingIntentForBroadcast = PendingIntent
                    .getBroadcast(this, notificationId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, notificationWhen, pendingIntentForBroadcast);
        } else {
            showToast("Alarms cannot be set for today or dates in the past.");
        }
    }```

This utilizes the helper method below, also in CourseDetailActivity:

```    private PendingIntent createPendingIntentForThisCourse(int courseId) {
        int termId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(TERM_ID_KEY);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(mainIntent);

        Intent termDetailIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TermDetailActivity.class);
        termDetailIntent.putExtra(TERM_ID_KEY, termId);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(termDetailIntent);

        Intent courseListIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CourseListActivity.class);
        courseListIntent.putExtra(TERM_ID_KEY, termId);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(courseListIntent);

        Intent courseDetailIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CourseDetailActivity.class);
        courseDetailIntent.putExtra(TERM_ID_KEY, termId);
        courseDetailIntent.putExtra(COURSE_ID_KEY, courseId);
        courseDetailIntent.setAction("foo_action");
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(courseDetailIntent);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(courseId, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return resultPendingIntent;
    }
````

MyReceiver class has the following onReceive method:

```
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onReceive: ");

        String channel_id = intent.getStringExtra(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_KEY);
        int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        String title = intent.getStringExtra(NOTIFICATION_TITLE_KEY);
        String text = intent.getStringExtra(NOTIFICATION_TEXT_KEY);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION_PENDING_INTENT_KEY);

        Toast.makeText(context, text + " (Notification ID " + notificationId + ")", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channel_id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_notification)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(text))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
    }
```

Quite by accident, I discovered that the extras for all other intents in the stack are being passed. It is ONLY the extras for the TOP stack that are not being passed (and therefore, the viewModel for the activity doesn't know which data to pull from the database to display.

I have scoured stackOverflow for hours and now days to now avail. I have tried to change the flags on the pendingIntent and on the Intent themselves. I tried to add a dummy action as suggested in another post. I've added a unique identifier as the request code for the intentToBroadcast. Nothing seems to have worked.

This code works on newer APIs; however, I am struggling to get it to work on API level 15.

I would very much appreciate any guidance you could give.

Comment: `TaskStackBuilder` appears in API level 16. It didn't exist in API level 15. Which version are you using (ie: which package/import of `TaskStackBuilder` are you using)?

Comment: Hey, @DavidWasser, my apologies for never getting back to you. For some reason, I didn't receive any sort of notification. (I'll have to go check my settings.) 

The API Level was indeed my issue. I ended up changing my target deploy to API Level 16, and went forward from there. Curious to know if you have any hints on how this same functionality would be accomplished at API Level 15? Thank you for your time!

Comment: You can use the version of `TaskStackBuilder` from the compatibility library: `androidx.core.app.TaskStackBuilder`. It offers similar functionality on older devices. It isn't **exactly** the same, but it is possible that the functionality you are after is implemented a way that works for you. Try it. Personally I don't like `TaskStackBuilder` because it makes a lot of assumptions and you really need to know **exactly** what it is doing under the covers or you will have strange behaviour that is difficult to debug.

Comment: @DavidWasser, thank you! I will give it a go. I appreciate your time and response.